# select same index in list box

Tags: c#, asp.net, selectedindexchanged

I am making a website in asp.net and I have 2 list boxes:

```
lbxPlayer1 and lbxPlayer2

lbxPlayer1.Items.Add("bob");
lbxPlayer1.Items.Add("jack");
lbxPlayer1.Items.Add("sam");

lbxPlayer2.Items.Add("fred");
lbxPlayer2.Items.Add("brian");
lbxPlayer2.Items.Add("dave");
```

they have both been populated with the same amount of values and i would like it so that when one of the lists is clicked the other list will select the same index.

how do i do this? i assume the code would be in the lbxPlayer1_SelectedIndexChanged event?

so when i click on "jack" i want "Brian" to also be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex.aspx) property:

```
int index = lbxPlayer1.SelectedIndex;
if(lbxPlayer2.Items.Count > index)
   lbxPlayer2.SelectedIndex = index;
```

If `SelectionMode` is `Multiple`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbxPlayer2.Items.Count; i++)
{ 
    if(i >= lbxPlayer1.Items.Count)
        lbxPlayer2.Items[i].Selected = false;
    else
        lbxPlayer2.Items[i].Selected = lbxPlayer1.Items[i].Selected;
}
```

---

**Update**

> well it tried it and nothing happened also tried this and nothing
>   happens either `lbxPlayer2.SelectedIndex = lbxPlayer1.SelectedIndex;`.
>   The dayabinding is getting done in the pageload event (which i cannot change), which i > believe is always o

Only databind them `if(!IsPostBack)` since `ViewState` will retain items across postbacks. So i assume that this event is never triggered because you rebind the `ListBoxes` on postbacks.

Comment: its not using multiple, and the top code you posted doesnt work

Comment: both the list have the same amount of values, so if there are 10 items in both list and i select the item at index 0 the if statment you posted wont go off

Comment: @BrianPeach why is that? 10 > 0

Comment: well it tried it and nothing happened also tried this and nothing happens either :\
lbxPlayer2.SelectedIndex = lbxPlayer1.SelectedIndex;

Comment: @BrianPeach: Of course the second did also not work since it is the same code as mine, just without the `if`. I'm sure that `lbxPlayer2.SelectedIndex=0` doesn't work either. Maybe you are databinding `lbxPlayer2` after you've changed the `SelectedIndex`. That would explain why you cannot change the selection.

Comment: well i think your right, the dayabinding is getting done in the pageload event (which i cannot change), which i belive is always occuring preventing this from working

Comment: @BrianPeach: Only databind them `if(!IsPostBack)` since `ViewState` will retain items across postbacks. So i assume that this event is never triggered because you rebind the `ListBoxes` on postbacks.

Comment: added if(!IsPostBack) and still no difference, the code exeutes but doesnt do anything :s

Comment: @BrianPeach: You should update your question, otherwise nobody knows what you have tried now and what was the result.