# How to select from a list box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, listbox, selectedindex

I am making a website in asp.net and I have 2 list boxes:

```
lbxPlayer1 and lbxPlayer2

lbxPlayer1.Items.Add("bob");
lbxPlayer1.Items.Add("jack");
lbxPlayer1.Items.Add("sam");

lbxPlayer2.Items.Add("fred");
lbxPlayer2.Items.Add("brian");
lbxPlayer2.Items.Add("dave");
```

they have both been populated with the same amount of values and i would like it so that when one of the lists is clicked the other list will select the same index.

how do i do this? i assume the code would be in the lbxPlayer1_SelectedIndexChanged event?

so when i click on "jack" i want "Brian" to also be selected.

Ive now realised that this is not something that wants to be done on the server side but on the client side, so i would like some help using javascript to do this;
so far ive been testing this bit of code in the lbxPlayer1_SelectedIndexChanged event

```
lbxPlayer1.Attributes["onchange"] =  "function{alert('Hello');}";
```

the above code is simply a tester but i cannot even get that to work?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once; if you think your original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180787/select-same-index-in-list-box) was incomplete or needs to be enhanced you can edit it directly.

Answer (score 3):

try out

```
lbxPlayer1.Attributes["onchange"] =  "changeindex(this) ";
```

in html javascript like this

```
function changeindex (obj) {
    var index = obj.selectedIndex;
    var select= document.getElementById('listbox2');
    select.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yu should know jQuery framework to work with javascript. It's a framework

Using the typicall javascript DOM elements

```
lbxPlayer1.Attributes["onchange"] =  "lbxPlayer1SelectedChange(this) "; //declaration of event
function lblPlayer1SelectedChange(element){
     document.getElementById("lbxPlayer2").selectedIndex = element.selectedIndex;
}
```

Using jQuery. Declaring event and function

```
$('.lbxPlayer1').change(function() {
    $('.lbxPlayer2 option')[this.selectedIndex].attr('selected','selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys thanks for your responces, however i could not get your code to work with my project (no errors, just nothing happened).
however your code has given me ideas and the solution:

ive added these 2 javascript functions

```
<script>
    function ChangePlayer2Lbx() 
    {
        var player1 = document.getElementById("lbxPlayer1");
        var player1index = player1.selectedIndex;
        var player2 = document.getElementById("lbxPlayer2");
        player2.selectedIndex = player1.selectedIndex;
    }
    function ChangePlayer1Lbx() 
    {
        var player2 = document.getElementById("lbxPlayer2");
        var player2index = player2.selectedIndex;
        var player1 = document.getElementById("lbxPlayer1");
        player1.selectedIndex = player2.selectedIndex;
    }
</script>
```

and i just added this to each of the list boxes html attributes.

```
onClick="ChangePlayer2Lbx()"
```

Thanks for all your quick responces and its working how i want it now :)